# inherit a style or find the style programmatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have a third party control that I assume gets a style from somewhere.
I have an subclass of that control, where I add an event handler. but now when I replace the old control in xaml with my overrided control, the style gets lost. I assume that its distinguishing between the superclass and subclass when it applies the style. How do I tell it that subclasses, like MyButton:ThirdPartyButton, should have the same style as ThirdPartyButton.

Or is there a programmatic way to see the source of the style like

```
ThirdPartyButton.GetDefaultStyleLocation();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a style in the resources which is implicitly applied:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MySubclass}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type thirdParty:Control}}"/>
```

This is necessary since styles are sadly not inherited.

Comment: This works for me, Thanks! I thought the style would come with it